# Sum of two random variables. Limits of integration

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ have pdf $$f_X(x)=e^{-x} \qquad  \text{ for } x \ge 0$$ and $Y$ have $$f_Y(y)=1 \qquad \text{ for } 0\le y \leq 1$$
$X, Y$ both independent. What is the pdf for $Z=X+Y$?

Using convolution formula I get $$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$$

How do I figure out my limits of integration? Since $f_X(x)$ is from $0\leq x \lt \infty$ so should $f_X(z-y)$ be. That makes want to integrate from $0$ to $z$, which is apparently wrong.

Comment: In your integral, as $y$ sweeps from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the _integrand_ must be $0$ except when $y \in [0,1]$, right? So straightaway, the limits of the integral can be reduced. Next, let's pick a _numerical value_ (say $3$) for $z$.  As $y$ sweeps from $0$ to $1$, is $f_X(3-y)$ _always_ nonzero? and if so, what _is_ $f_X(3-y)$? What if we had chosen $z=5$ instead? or $z=9.382$? Just when you were ready to jump to conclusions, I suggest: try it for $z = 0.5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the densities
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= 1_{0<y<1} \\ f_X(x) &= 1_{x > 0} e^{-x} 
\end{align}
so that the convolution becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{0<z-x<1} 1_{x > 0} e^{-x} dx 
&= \int_{\max(0, z-1)}^z  e^{-x} dx 
\\&= e^{-\max(0, z-1)} - e^{-z} \\
f_Z(z)&= e^{\min(0, 1-z)} - e^{-z}
\end{align}